# Twitter gem search results pagination

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

How I can paginate SearchResults data with "search" method. For example fetch results by 10 tweets per page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to deal with search result pages at all. As `Twitter::SearchResults` includes the [`Twitter::Enumerable`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/enumerable.rb) module (which in turn includes [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html)), you can just use something like `results.take(20)` to get up to 20 tweets. The module handles pagination automatically in the background for you.

That said, you can still tell twitter how many results it should return per page. You can pass the `:count` option to the `search` method like this:

```
client.search("to:justinbieber marry me", count: 20).take(30).each do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text
end
```

According to the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets#api-param-search_count), you can set any value there up to 100.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I don't understand. 
I want to search tweets with "ruby" word, my code for example:
`$twitter.search("ruby", count: 10).take(30).each do |tweet|; puts tweet.text;end`
It always returns me 30 tweets, I just want to get 10 per request (3 pages) and paginate them with kaminari for example.